# Server side not render http requests [Angular Universal]

Tags: angular, angular-universal, universal-cli

I have problem to get any staff from http request from apis when I do 'view source', it looks like that staff not comming from server.

So I can see static html in source but nothing from http requests....

Anyone know what can be a problem?

I am using `universal-cli`

**Edit:**

here is example of http call from my `showcode.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class ShowcodeService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCode(id): any{
     return this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + 'code/show/' + id)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  };

}
```

Here is live example: http://pushsc.com/show/code/58bc83760a58d602a0b99d14 check source code of html... It render evertying expect things that comes from http...

Comment: Post your template and typescript please

Comment: What part you need? I used `universal-cli` created project like this `ung new project`

Comment: The typescript - of the http calls.

Comment: I updated my main question... Added http call from my service...

Comment: @Vladimir you are still having that issue?

Comment: @Araving It is new one, now I don't get things rendered on server side from http requests... Check here: http://pushsc.com/show/code/58bc83760a58d602a0b99d14

Comment: `http.get()` method gets called once you subscribe this, otherwise it will do nothing

Comment: I got similar problem, due to server.js was'nt compiled/updated correctly. Can you check inside your server.js file if it contains your method ?

Comment: imho angular universal should have that part, making a simple http call and pre-rendering it. It is 2018 and I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Angular 6) Angular Universal - Not waiting on content API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270397/angular-6-angular-universal-not-waiting-on-content-api-call)

Answer (score 2):

Try update your angular to 4.0.0.

They fixed some bugs which was related to server side rendering.

Comment: I'd also recommend updating to Angular 4. However, universal-cli does not work (yet) using the modules and services from `platform-server`.

Comment: I've spend half a week to get over this, and then developed an example app in order that other people do not suffer from this:https://github.com/nglibs/universal-example-app

Comment: Hi @BurakTasci can you please tell me how did you solve htis issue? the main key of the issue. Best!